# Adding additional taxonomies to wordpress taxonomy page

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type 'packages' with multiple taxonomies; i.e. 'destination'

i.e. mysite.com/destination/new-zealand/

The post type 'packages' also has other taxonomies, i.e. 'difficulty'

I wish to filter these area pages; something like: mysite.com/destination/new-zealand/?difficulty=medium

Here is the WP_Query:

```
$term_id = "12"; //medium
$taxquery = array(     
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'packages',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'difficulty',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $term_id,
            'operator'=> 'IN'
        ))
 );
```

Comment: It seems to me that you want to combine two taxonomies and serveral terms with the `AND` operator in the query. For example, get `packages` with `new-zealand` in destination taxonomy AND `medium` in `difficulty` taxonomy. Can you clarify it?

Comment: Yes that is correct, using the relation AND works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// 12 - difficulty
// destination
// get Id current taxonomy
$this_term = get_queried_object();

        $taxquery = array(     
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'post_type' => 'packages',    
                      'tax_query' => array(
                               'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'difficulty',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => array( 12 ),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'destination',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => array( $this_term->term_id) // Id current taxonomy
        )
    )
        );
```